# How to change input type according to the option value?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the input type according to the option value.

If the date option is selected, the type of input field should be changed into date type.

```js
function func2() {
  if (document.getElementById('field_search').value=="khao_date") {
    document.getElementById('input_search').type == 'date';
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('input_search').type == 'text';
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="field_search" name="field_search" size=1 onchange="func2()">
  <option value="khao_date">Date</option>
  <option value="khao_detail">Detail</option>
</select>

<input id="input_search" type="text">
```

but somehow it doesn't change. Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setAttribute('type', '...')` instead. Tested on Chrome..

```js
function func2() {
  if (document.getElementById('field_search').value=="khao_date") {
    document.getElementById('input_search').setAttribute('type', 'date');
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('input_search').setAttribute('type', 'text');
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="field_search" name="field_search" size=1 onchange="func2()">
  <option value="khao_date">Date</option>
  <option value="khao_detail">Detail</option>
</select>

<input id="input_search" type="text">
```